# Introductory text to Peter Lax Theorem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods

I'm looking for Numerical Analysis's books that explains about Finite Difference, Convergence, Consistency and Estability in a introductory level, moreover I want see some applications of Peter Lax Theorem in PDE's.

PS: My background in Numerical Analysis is a null set.

Comment: Which one(s) of Lax's many theorems are you particularly interested in?

Comment: @ekkilop This one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_equivalence_theorem

Comment: I work with the first one given by wiki having numerical analysis background, I think it will be suitable for you, you can find it here

http://libgen.io/search.php?req=Finite+Difference+Schemes+and+Partial+Differential+Equations&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend "Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equation: Steady state and time-dependent problems", by Randall J. LeVeque. In the second chapter he shows how to prove convergence of finite difference schemes that are consistent and stable at a fairly introductory level

The back of the book actually has an endorsement by Peter Lax himself!